# SQL databases: normalization vs. performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, database-schema

For a project, I was asked to look at an existing SQL database and to see if it could be improved. It was basically a customer database with a bunch of different types of data per customer. This is (basically) how it was organized:

Each customer had a row in the customer table with a customer ID. Then for each type of data, each customer had its own table. So, for instance, there would not be one central table for "jobs", with a customer ID in each row, but for each customer there would be a jobs table called "jobs1234" (1234 being a customer ID.

Now, my first response was confusion as to why you would organize it like that. I've always just learned that it's always better to normalize without really thinking beyond that point. But when I discussed it with people, a few pointed out it may have been for performance reasons. They said that if there were too many rows for "jobs", it would be better to have them split up per customer than to have them all in one table.

Something about indexing and the customer ID being the identifier. I'm confused as to why this approach would improve performance and haven't really gotten a very clear answer so far. Can anyone explain to me why that's the case and if it's even true that this approach is better in some cases?

Comment: What you described has nothing to do with normalization.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall', maybe I'm misunderstanding, but: "database normalization is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize redundancy and dependency". Doesn't that actually have a lot to do with this situation? It would help if you explained what you meant by the remark instead of just saying it's "wrong".

Comment: Normalization concerns itself with certain kinds of dependencies among columns. You're describing certain kinds of dependencies among rows. (All the rows in "jobs1234" belong to the customer 1234.) The search term for that is "partitioning". All the current, major client/server dbms have native support for partitioning. I'd go with a do-it-myself approach only as a last resort. I'd even consider changing platforms to avoid doing it myself.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Ah, cheers for that. I didn't know that term yet. By the 'normalization' part I was referring to completely restructuring this bogus schema, not the way it's organized now if that's how it came across. (Was probably still the wrong word for it  then, but still)

Comment: *Restructuring* works fine for that. Normalization is widely misunderstood. Probably 90% of the questions that are expressed in terms of normalization have nothing to do with normalization. (90% of the answers, too.) You're less likely to solve a normalization problem correctly if you can't *recognize* a normalization problem. Ditto for partitioning and indexing problems. (That's an observation, not a criticism.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I find this statement rather shocking:

> They said that if there were too many rows for "jobs", it would be
>   better to have them split up per customer than to have them all in one
>   table.

Databases are designed to have tables that have lots and lots of rows -- millions of rows should be no problem.  You don't specify what the volume of data is, but with a name like `jobs`, I'd be surprised if the total volume exceeds a few million rows in total.  For this volume of data, a single table with suitable indexes should be fine.

There are cases where splitting data by customer *would* make sense.  The strongest case is when it is an *explicit* requirement, typically for security reasons.  In other words, the clients are promised that "their data is never mixed with anyone else's data".  And, in most databases (MySQL included), it is easier to deal with security at the table level than at the row level.

Another possible reason would be when the tables have different formats, reflecting different data for each customer.  In this case, you would really be dealing separate applications, and each customer should have their own database.

Are there any the downsides to splitting the customer data into multiple tables per customer?  Yes.  Here are some:

1. You cannot write generic queries/views to access the data.  Basically, all queries in the code need to by dynamic, so you can put in the right table name.
2. Maintaining the data becomes cumbersome.  Instad of updating a single table, you have to update multiple tables.
3. Answering questions such as "How many jobs does each customer have?" or "What is the growth in the number of jobs over time?" become so difficult to answer that people probably won't even bother asking them.
4. Performance is a mixed bag.  Although you might save the overhead of storing the customer id in each table, you incur another cost.  Having lots of smaller tables means lots of tables with partially filled pages.  Depending on the number of jobs per customer and number of overall customers, you might actually be multiplying the amount of space used.  In the worst case of one job per customer where a page contains -- say -- 100 jobs, you would be multiplying the required space by about 100.
5. The last point also applies to the page cache in memory.  So, data in one table that would fit into memory might not fit into memory when split among many tables.

Partitioning is one way to implement something similar.  However, this would work best when the query load is focused on one customer at a time.  If all customers are accessing the data at the same time, then partitioning is going to be less of a win, and indexing should be sufficient.

Unless there is a really good reason for splitting the data into separate tables (a requirement, cumbersome security for each client, or custom formats for each client), you simply would not take that approach.  Even when there are reasons for doing it, there are often other solutions (such as partitioning) that solve the same problem.

Comment: *"In other words, the clients are promised that "their data is never mixed with anyone else's data."* I've been told that some regulatory environments require things like this, but I haven't worked on any systems like that myself.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' . . . Regulatory requirements can be more onerous, requiring separate databases on separate machines (and sometimes not even on the same subnetwork).  The separation of data arises (in my experience) when competing companies are working together on some common system to help the industry.